# Why can cloud's bottoms be flat?

Tags: physical-chemistry, everyday-chemistry, water

I've always wondered why clouds can have flat bottoms, and have debated to myself whether it was a difference in atmospheric pressures, or some water molecule tendency? Could someone shed light?

Comment: Curiously, one might argue that clouds do not have flat bottoms, they're just invisible below a certain height! Here's [a fun and very accessible video from Minute Earth](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QC2x_RRnk8E) which brings it up.

Comment: @NicolauSakerNeto Wow! Thanks that was really cool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That many types of clouds have flat bottoms is a function of decreasing air temperature with increasing height, and the water vapor pressure, commonly in this context called the dew point, of the air. When some force causes a non-cloudy parcel of air to rise, moisture will condense out as cloud particles just as soon as the air temperature reaches the dew point of the air mass.  The colder air (higher up) then contains a cloud, where the warmer air (even just slightly above the dew point) below the cloud remains clear.